# How to change Default Module Icon

Tags: magento2, module, icon

I'm looking for how to change module icon. As I can see, the Dashboard,Product,Sales,Marketing have the icon like this.

[image]

And my own module icon (***GiftRegistry***) like this:

[image]

I want to change my default icon. How can i do that?

Comment: Take a look here: http://ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-how-to-create-custom-menu-in-admin-and-change-default-font-icon